# is it possible to change the beep sound , using Linux shell script command

Tags: bell

I am using this command to beep

```
tput bel 
echo -e "\a"
```

I need to change the beep tone with some tone using some other command.

Comment: see also the `xset b` command.

Comment: In what environment? Text console or X11? What do you know about available sound hardware? What makes you think that the user hasn't set up a visual bell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not bash related question, it depends on what terminal emulator you use. For example with urxvt: `URxvt.bell-command: play /my/beep.wav`

If you want to compose speaker music, use the `beep` command.